# Python console not working in QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, python, mac

Trying to open Python in QGIS returns this:

```
Failed to open Python console:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 46, in show_console
    _console = PythonConsole(parent)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.console = PythonConsoleWidget(self)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.shell = ShellScintilla(self)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console_sci.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.refreshSettingsShell()
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console_sci.py", line 141, in refreshSettingsShell
    self.setCaretForegroundColor(cursorColor)
TypeError: setCaretForegroundColor(self, QColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'unicode'


Python version:
2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]

QGIS version:
2.18.9 'Las Palmas', exported

Python path:
['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', u'/Users/Malaquias/.qgis2/python', u'/Users/Malaquias/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', u'/Users/Malaquias/.qgis2//python']
```

Deleted and reinstalled QGIS multiple times. No dice.